# Angular Table: How to capture first row of sorted table (No jQuery)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having an angular table with ng-repeat and all...Table is being loaded with sorting of 1st column...

I want to capture 1st row data after page is full loaded....

I think 1 have 2 question here:

1. How to call any method in angular only after page is loaded full?
2. How to capture 1st row data?

Thanks in advance
Samit

Answer (score 0):

1. you can use the `angular.element(document).ready()` to hook on ready events.
2. For the first row data, can't you just use array accessors to retrieve it since you already have ng-repeat on it.

   `$scope.elements = [1,3,4,5]; // elements bound to ng-repeat.` and then 
   `var firstRowData = $scope.elements[0];`

Comment: Nope....1st one : angular.element(document).ready() is getting called as soon as page is loading...i have table, and doc viweing on my page and I need to call a method only after everything is being laoded on page.

Comment: Perhaps you are loading those in an asynchronous call. In that case, its best to use promises to call method. For better help, could you share a fiddle?

Comment: ya..u got it correct...but I dont have any fiddle...can u plz post any promise example

Comment: I did all and then since nothing I found so I have to write here....anyways...I will figure it out....Thanks to all for ur time n help

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it, may be not the best solutions but it working well...

For 1st item, check start time before making json call and once call is completed, capture time again (in ms)..take the difference call $timeout with that much of delay.

2nd item, use ng-mouseover and capture row details whatever u want...

Suggestions are most welcome